# compiling package, including jars via command line

Tags: java, unix, netbeans, jar, javac

I'm using the Netbeans IDE but im trying to compile and run my
project via the unix shell:

- I have a package: **project/src/packageName/.java files**
- And my    jars: **project/lib/.jar files**

The classes under src/packagename/.. more or less depend on each other and they're also using said libraries.

I added the libraries via Netbeans (though
NetBeans couldnt recognize the classes from the libraries I used in
my project, so I needed to extract the .jar files first and direct
NetBeans to the extracted jar folders containing the .class files
from the library).

When I run the class containing the main() method in NetBeans it works just fine.
But I'm trying to accomplish this with the unix shell using javac.

My question: How do I compile my project including the jars/foreign library.
I already tried the following:

```
javac -classpath ".:jar1.jar:jar2.jar:" /path/to/project/src/packageName *.java
```

It still said that symbol cannot be found (refering to classes from library)

Sorry if this question was answered somewhere else already, but after a few hours of research I couldn't get it working.
I guess I'm doing something horribly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do read Java documentation for `javac`, here is [JDK14 javac](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/javac.html#standard-options).

There are plenty of other options you can try especially if you want to define different file encodings or JRE source/targets.

You can simplify command if using relative path from current directory, just `cd` to your project directory first. Here is a simple call:

```
javac -d build/my.classes -sourcepath src -cp lib/abc.jar:lib/xyz.jar  src/packageName/*.java
```

You may need to `mkdir build` or some other directory to store temporary files. After this you could try running your app with direct command for `java` on the files.